# Drupal Restful API

Tags: 7

I have quick question about Drupal Restful API modules.

There is a restful web services module https://www.drupal.org/project/restws
and there is another restful module https://www.drupal.org/project/restful

I cannot figure what's the exact difference between the two. As, both supports CRUD operations, json format. So, what's the exact difference between two.

Thanks!

Comment: Except the fact that one is used by 1,892 sites and has a stable release, and the other by 69 sites and only in development version?

Comment: I would suggest using the Services module https://www.drupal.org/project/services

Comment: I would recommend RestWS as it has the most flexibility and granularity for json. You have these options: HTTPRL, Services, XMLRPC.php, Views Data Export, RestWS, and cis_connector.

Answer (score 2):

One of the maintainers of the module [gave a good explanation on this issue](https://github.com/RESTful-Drupal/restful/issues/371#issuecomment-70457895):

> Here are the differences between RESTful and other modules, such as RestWs and
>   Services Entity:
>
> - RESTful requires explicitly declaring the exposed API. When enabling the module, nothing happens until a plugin declares it.
> - Resources are exposed by bundle, rather than by entity. This would allow a developer to expose only nodes of a certain type, for example.
> - The exposed properties need to be explicitly declared. This allows a clean output without Drupal's internal implementation leaking out. This means the consuming client doesn't need to know if an entity is a node or a term, nor will they be presented with the field_ prefix.
> - Resource versioning is built-in, so that resources can be reused with multiple consumers. The versions are at the resource level, for more flexibility and control.
> - It has configurable output formats. It ships with JSON (the default one), JSON+HAL and as an example also XML.
> - Audience is developers and not site builders.
> - Provide a key tool for a headless Drupal. See the AngularJs form example module.